# Algorithm to get all biconnected components (of any size, not the maximal subgraph) out of a graph?

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

I am working on a project/game that uses graphs as the world space. I need to be able to get all the biconnected components out of the graph. I know you immediately want to say "Tarjans" but I specifically need to get the biconnected components of ANY SIZE. That is, any subgraph that is bioconnected I want to detect.

At first, I made the very bad assumption that I could simply look for cycles and call it a day... A very easy example graph can disprove that.
So, now the current algorithm I have made/ even implemented is a cycle detection that looks for paths that "cut across" the cycle, like a chord in a circle.

The algorithm is a modified DFS that finds cycles, and then upon finding a cycle, another DFS is called from that last node found in the cycle to find paths across the cycle, where it returns the cycle + the path(s) as a new biconnected component.

I suppose the question is "does this work?" combined with "is there an algorithm you are aware of that does this already that I ought to use?"

```py
def run_find_minimal_bicomps(dfg):
    cycles = []
    node = dfg.node_olist[0]
    path = []
    find_minimal_bicomps(current=node, dfg=dfg, path=path, bicomps=cycles)
    cycles = list(set(tuple(sorted(cycle)) for cycle in cycles))
    cycles = [cycle for cycle in cycles if len(cycle) > 2]
    return cycles


def find_minimal_bicomps(current, dfg, path, bicomps):
    path.append(current)
    for adj_node in current.adj_obj:
        if adj_node in path:  # cycle in the path...
            cycle = path[path.index(adj_node):]  # make the cycle
            if len(cycle) > 2 and cycle not in bicomps:
                bicomps.append(cycle)
                all_paths = []
                find_chords(cycle=cycle, current=adj_node, dfg=dfg, path=[], bicomps=bicomps, parent=None, root=adj_node, all=all_paths)
                if len(all_paths) > 1:
                    cycle_and_all_paths = cycle
                    for chord in all_paths:
                        cycle_and_all_paths = cycle_and_all_paths + chord
                    bicomps.append(list(set(cycle_and_all_paths)))
        else:
            find_minimal_bicomps(current=adj_node, dfg=dfg, path=path, bicomps=bicomps)
    if current in path:
        path.remove(current)


def find_chords(cycle, current, dfg, path, bicomps, parent, root, all):
    # dfs the graph for a path to a node in the cycle
    # anytime a path to the other side of the graph add the cycle + the path to the bicomp list
    for adj in current.adj_obj:
        if adj == parent: continue
        if (adj not in path) and (adj not in cycle):  # found node to explore
            path.append(adj)
            find_chords(cycle=cycle, current=adj, dfg=dfg, path=path, bicomps=bicomps, parent=current, root=root, all=all)
        elif (adj not in path) and (adj in cycle) and (adj is not root):  # found node on the cycle
            print('cycle: ' + str([n.nid for n in cycle]))
            print('chord:' + str([n.nid for n in path]))
            bicomps.append(cycle + path)
            if len(path) > 0:
                all.append(copy.copy(path))
    if current in path:
        path.remove(current)
```

You will not be able to run this as it depends on a data structure DFG.

"bicomp" here, refers to biconnected component.

If you notice any obvious optimizations, they are more than welcome. In the same vein, I'm new to python, so if there is a great "pythonic" way of doing something here, that is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A **biconnected component** is a maximal biconnected subgraph.

A **graph** is said to be **biconnected** if:

- It is connected, i.e. it is possible to reach every vertex from every
  other vertex, by a simple path.
- Even after removing any vertex the    graph remains connected.

A graph is biconnected if it has no vertex such that its removal increases the number of connected components in the graph. And if there exists such a vertex then it is not Biconnected. A vertex whose removal increases the number of connected components is called an **Articulation Point**.

To find all the biconnected components of a graph, you need to tweak the algorithm of finding articulation points.

The idea is to store visited edges in a stack while DFS on a graph and keep looking for Articulation Points. As soon as an Articulation Point is found, all edges visited while DFS from articulation point onwards will form one biconnected component. When DFS completes for one connected component, all edges present in stack will form a biconnected component.

If there is no Articulation Point in graph, then graph is biconnected and so there will be one biconnected component which is the graph itself.

[GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biconnected-components/) 
[Hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/biconnected-components/tutorial/)

Comment: I understand all of this. My point is that I not only need to detect the maximal biconnected subgraphs of a graph, but ANY subgraph that is biconnected.
A trivial (and inefficient) way would be to look at each subgraph and see if it is biconnected. That, however would be too complex as these graphs get pretty large. 
Does that make sense? I want to find every subgraph that is biconnected, not just the biconnected components of a graph.